# Context Provider runs again on file picker open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have got this Context and context provider:

```
"use client";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const modalContext = createContext({ isVisible: false, setVisible: null });

export const ModalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState();

  console.log("Called from provider");

  return (
    <modalContext.Provider value={{ isVisible: isVisible, setVisible: setVisible }}>
      {children}
    </modalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

When I open the file picker, then the log "Called from the provider" runs again.

I am expecting to run the `ModalProvider` run only the first time.

Comment: You open and close your modal by calling `setVisible`, a state setter that's designed to trigger a re-render

Comment: @YoussoufOumar but it's called when i click the choose file  button input I don't think it should rerender that time